# mutate arithmetic using dplyr::lag

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to automate calculating the difference in means from a grouped `mean_se` table. But using `lag()` in a `mutate` function produces `NA's`.

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_modify(~ mean_se(.x$Sepal.Length)) %>% mutate(difference = y-lag(y))
```

What I would like is a difference column that says `NA`, 0.93,  0.65

A harder case would be to specify the particular category against which to calculate the operation, for example `filter(marital == "No answer")` so that the mean differences in each raceXmarital status are calculated against the values of "No answer" in the marital column (34, 64 and 56)

```
gss_cat %>% group_by(race, marital) %>% 
  group_modify(~ mean_se(.x$age))
```

Answer (score 0):

The group attribute is still present after the `mutate` unless we do `ungroup`.  There is no equivalent option is `mutate` as in `summarise` i.e. `.groups = 'drop'`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>% 
   group_modify(~ mean_se(.x$Sepal.Length)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(difference = y-lag(y))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Species        y  ymin  ymax difference
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 setosa      5.01  4.96  5.06     NA    
2 versicolor  5.94  5.86  6.01      0.93 
3 virginica   6.59  6.50  6.68      0.652
```

Essentially, when we have a single row (i.e. here the output after the `group_modify` is a single row per group) and we take the `lag` it is just NA because the `default` option is `NA`

```
lag(5)
[1] NA
```

and any value subtracted from `NA` returns `NA`

```
6 - NA
[1] NA
```

---

For the second case, the data is grouped by two columns, therefore, we can change the grouping to 'race' and do the subtraction by subsetting

```
library(forcats)
data(gss_cat)
gss_cat %>% 
  group_by(race, marital) %>% 
  group_modify(~ mean_se(.x$age)) %>% 
  group_by(race) %>% 
  mutate(diff = y - y[marital == 'No answer']) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 x 6
   race  marital           y  ymin  ymax   diff
   <fct> <fct>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Other No answer      34    28    40     0   
 2 Other Never married  30.2  29.8  30.6  -3.79
 3 Other Separated      42.5  41.3  43.8   8.54
 4 Other Divorced       45.5  44.7  46.3  11.5 
 5 Other Widowed        64.5  62.7  66.3  30.5 
 6 Other Married        42.2  41.8  42.7   8.24
 7 Black No answer      64    NA    NA     0   
 8 Black Never married  34.5  34.2  34.8 -29.5 
 9 Black Separated      46.2  45.2  47.1 -17.8 
10 Black Divorced       51.0  50.4  51.5 -13.0 
11 Black Widowed        67.5  66.7  68.4   3.53
12 Black Married        46.4  46.0  46.9 -17.6 
13 White No answer      56    50.1  61.9   0   
14 White Never married  34.4  34.2  34.7 -21.6 
15 White Separated      45.6  44.9  46.2 -10.4 
16 White Divorced       51.6  51.3  51.8  -4.44
17 White Widowed        72.8  72.5  73.1  16.8 
18 White Married        49.7  49.5  49.8  -6.32
```